# R: Error: non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I'm trying to generate a new variable by adding two existing numerical variables in R. I know I could use the following code, and it worked.

Here's a data sample:

```
B01001_SEX_BY_AGE <- structure(list(GEOID = "04000US17", `Geography Name` = "Illinois", 
               `Total Population` = 12851684, Male = 6310460, `Male: Under 5 years` = 403373, `Female: Under 5 years` = 406002), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                              -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


B01001_SEX_BY_AGE$"Under 5 years"= B01001_SEX_BY_AGE$"Male: Under 5 years" + B01001_SEX_BY_AGE$"Female: Under 5 years"
```

But as you can see, I have long names for my data frame and variables. So having to reference both the data frame and the variable name in these expressions can get pretty messy. I tried the following alternative methods, but they all got the same error. `Evaluation ERROR: non-numeric argument to binary operator`. I also tried adding `as.numeric()`for those variables and replacing the spaces in the variable names with underscores, still didn't work.

```
#Method 1

attach(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE)
B01001_SEX_BY_AGE$"Under 5 years"= "Male: Under 5 years" + "Female: Under 5 years"
detach(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE)



#Method 2

B01001_SEX_BY_AGE <- transform(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE,
                 "Under 5 years" = "Male: Under 5 years" + "Female: Under 5 years"
)

#Method 3

library(dplyr)
B01001_SEX_BY_AGE <- mutate(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE,"Under 5 years" = "Male: Under 5 years" + "Female: Under 5 years")
```

All return the following error in the Console:

```
Error in "Male Under 5 years" + "Female_Under_5_years" : 
      non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I'd greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: If you provide the data, it will be much easier for people to help you.  You can use the `dput` command to create R syntax to recreate your data, and you can subset your data if there are too many rows to easily post.  For example `dput(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE[1:6,])`

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I used the dput() and added data to my question.

Comment: I think the example data is not correct, there is only 1 row and 6 columns.  Perhaps you typed `dput(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE[,1:6])` and meant to type `dput(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE[1:6,])`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. The axample data is now fixed.

Comment: In your data sample, you don't have a column named `Female: Under 5 years`.  But in general, you're better off using `dplyr`'s `mutate` function to create new columns by applying operations (eg, adding) to or between existing columns

Comment: @Punintended Thanks. I fixed the problem in the sample. I've tried `dplyr`'s `mutate` function, it gives me the same error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using backticks instead of double quotes for the names with spaces

```
library(dplyr)
B01001_SEX_BY_AGE <- mutate(B01001_SEX_BY_AGE,`Under 5 years` = `Male: Under 5 years` + `Female: Under 5 years`)
```

Comment: Argh, I was *just* typing this out

Comment: @KerryJackson It worked. The importance of punctuation in coding! Thank you so much!!